# is there any O(logn) solution for [1+2a+3a^2+4a^3+....+ba^(b-1)] MOD M

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose we have a series summation 
*s = 1 + 2a + 3a^2 + 4a^3 + .... + ba^(b-1)*

i need to find s MOD M, where M is a prime number and b is relatively big integer.

I have found an O((log n)^2) divide and conquer solution.
where, 
g(n) = (1 + a + a^2 + ... + a^n) MOD M

f(a, b) = [f(a, b/2) + a^b/2*(f(a,b/2) + b/2*g(b/2))] MOD M, where b is even number
f(a,b) = [f(a,b/2) + a^b/2*(f(a,b/2) + b/2*g(b/2)) + ba(b-1)] MOD M, where b is odd number

is there any O(log n) solution for this problem?

Comment: not answering the question, but a thought. you can calculate all `a^[1..n]` in one pass, with N Multiplications. or even cache the results for further use if you need.

Comment: Is *n* the same as *b*, so you are looking for an O(log b) solution, assuming *a* and *M* to be constant?

Comment: Note that `s` can be expressed in closed form as `(1 - (b+1) a^b + b a^(b+1)) / (1 - a)^2`. If `(a-1)` is relatively prime to `m`, this should give an easy solution. If not, it's a bit messier.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Observe that `1 + 2a + 3a^2 + ... + ba^(b-1)` is the derivative in `a` of `1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^b`. (The field of formal power series covers a lot of tricks like this.) We can evaluate the latter with [automatic differentiation with dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers) in time `O(log b)` arithmetic ops. Something like this:

```
def fdf(a, b, m):
    if b == 0:
        return (1, 0)
    elif b % 2 == 1:
        f, df = fdf((a**2) % m, (b - 1) / 2, m)
        df *= 2 * a
        return ((1 + a) * f % m, (f + (1 + a) * df) % m)
    else:
        f, df = fdf((a**2) % m, (b - 2) / 2, m)
        df *= 2 * a
        return ((1 + (a + a**2) * f) % m, (
            (1 + 2 * a) * f + (a + a**2) * df) % m)
```

The answer is `fdf(a, b, m)[1]`. Note the use of the chain rule when we go from the derivative with respect to `a**2` to the derivative with respect to `a`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.